# Static Analysis tool recommendation for Java?

Tags: java, static-analysis

Being vaguely familiar with the Java world I was googling for a static analysis tool that would also was intelligent enough to fix the issues it finds. I ran at CodePro tool but, again, I'm new to the Java community and don't know the vendors.

What tool can you recommend based on the criteria above?

Comment: you can also take a look at [qulice.com](http://www.qulice.com), which integrates together Checkstyle, PMD, FindBugs, and pre-configures them

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com will be your friend.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

FindBugs, PMD and Checkstyle are all excellent choices especially if you integrate them into your build process.

At my last company we also used [Fortify](http://www.fortify.com) to check for potential security problems. We were fortunate to have an enterprise license so I don't know the cost involved.

Answer (score 48):

- [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)
- [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net)
- [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net)
- [Lint4J](http://www.jutils.com)
- [Classycle](http://classycle.sourceforge.net)
- [JDepend](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jdepends)
- [SISSy](http://sissy.sourceforge.net)
- [Google Codepro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/)

Comment: Will you please comment a bit on your use of lint4j? I just tried it, but it produced only a single warning (a false positive!) on my entire code base. I know my code isn't that clean! My code requires Java 6, and the lint4j proj. seems to be inactive. lint4j is not FOSS, so no source code. Thanks!

Comment: I got several hundred warnings from lint4j during my scan of 200 KLOC project. Most of them were "nice to have" like "use a character literal instead of String literal to append a single constant character to a stream". Findbugs definitely gives you the more important things to consider. (But on new code I always use both of them!)

Answer (score 13):

I recommend FindBugs.  http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/ Good in assisting to do code review.

Comment: findbugs is no longer maintained and was superseded by [spotbugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/)

Answer (score 11):

IntelliJ IDEA from JetBrains.  They also do ReSharper in the .Net community.

Answer (score 7):

[Sonar](http://sonar.codehaus.org/) is a quality control tool. It gauges quality of Java applications through the observance of coding rules conventions, metric measures and advanced indicators.

Sonar is based on the following projects :

- [JavaNCSS](http://www.kclee.de/clemens/java/javancss/): Quality Metrics
- [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/): Style Cheking
- [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/): Code scanning for potential errors.
- [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/): Test Coverage

You could also use [Simian](http://www.redhillconsulting.com.au/products/simian/) for duplication detection.

Comment: I don't like Sonar - they began to be very very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

[CRAP4J](http://crap4j.org/) is not only an awesome name but it's quite useful. The other good ones are all above, best of all (IMHO) is FindBugs, because it really does find honest-to-goodness bugs right away in a big code base.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [JavaDepend](http://www.javadepend.com), it complement other static analysis tools, and provides a CQL language  to query code like database,

JavaDepend provides also many interactive views to understand the existing code base and more than 82 metrics.

Answer (score 0):

All the above are great tools. PMD is probably the most common.

Another tool is [Enerjy](http://www.enerjy.com/). It recently became free, so you can download it and try for yourself. Enerjy is somewhat more organized and a better fit to larger teams. It makes it easier to customize and share the rules. Personally, I'm not a big fan, but maybe you'll fancy it more than I do.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of commercial vendors that have a Java offering:

[Klocwork](http://www.klocwork.com)
[Coverity](http://www.coverity.com)

They won't "fix the issues" they find (nor will, I believe, any of the other ones mentioned above) but these are all tools that have varying strengths.