# JDepend ant taskdef example?

Tags: java

I am examining some java static analysis tools.

findbugs, checkstyle, javancss, pmd and jdepend. A previous stackoverflow question regarding tool recommendations [Static Analysis tool recommendation for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97599/static-analysis-tool-recommendation-for-java)

My problem, the only tool I am having an issue with running is jdepend.
The homepage is http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html.

I have followed the installation instructions and I have tried the example target.
But it did not work for me. Listing missing jars.

Regardless of it working or not. 
I would prefer to have a taskdef, defining classpath, and classname.
I cant find an example of this. Does anyone have a working example of this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a static tool (a jar file, example findbugs.jar) has a taskdef (FindBugsTask) inside. When you declare the taskdef in ant build.xml file, the jar file (findbugs.jar) is found and run.

But, with jdepend:

- jdepend.jar does not include taskdef (JdependTask)
- ant can understand jdepend task

It's mean that, you must include jdepend.jar into CLASSPATH

2 Solutions:

1. use CLASSPATH: export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:path_to_jdepend.jar
2. in ant command line: ant -f  -lib path_to_jdepend.jar