# Java Code Analysis Tool

Tags: java, code-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Static Analysis tool recommendation for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97599/static-analysis-tool-recommendation-for-java)

I have to find a java code analysis or inspection tool which can customized with user defined rule.
Actually, I have to make some static code in my workspace to non-static. a tool where i can write some rules like if such a code is encountered in entire workspace then do something.

Can anyone suggest something.

Comment: please check once , you can find many post on the same topic

Comment: Possibility Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/97599/668970

Answer (score 10):

You can use

1. [Google CodePro Analytix](http://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/) (Free)(one of my favourate tool),
2. [SpotBugs](https://spotbugs.github.io) (formerly known as [Findbugs](https://github.com/findbugsproject/findbugs))
3. [PMD](https://pmd.github.io)
4. [Checkstyle](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle)
5. [Sonar](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarjava.html) - It's also good because it integrates all Findbugs, PMD, Checkstyle in one place and very well dashboard reporting available

Answer (score 3):

[PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) is extensible. The rules are file based and can be coded either in Java or XPath.

Comment: been there... in large project 90% of the problems pmd finds are worthless, so you end up with "// no pmd" comment :)

Comment: The trick with PMD is that you limit the rule set to the rules you really want to use. If you activate 100%, then of course, most results are not useful. But that's not the way to do it ;) ([Best Practices](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/bestpractices.html))

Comment: any good set of rules you came across? The best practices sucks as well... I'd appreciate you sharing this info.

Comment: There is no "good" set of rules. If you do serious coding, you agree on a few rules within your team, activate them, put them on warning first and on error (= breaks build) after a some weeks/months. It's a tool. It does not *make* better software. *You* define your quality standards, pmd (and all the other tools) help in reaching and keeping *your* standards.

Answer (score 3):

If you want standalone tool http://www.sonarsource.org/ provides static analysis by using PMD, Findbugs, Checkstyles etc. You can define your own importance levels for all rules and modify rules.

It also integrates to Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

1.[pmd](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/)

2.[findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)

3.[checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/)

I found pmd is very useful.