# code analysis tools for starting on a new project

Tags: java, eclipse

i am starting on a new project that has been going on for 
almost a year. I wanted to do code analysis before i start coding , having a good picture of all 
the flows. I wanted to see the project structure , the references to libraries , etc... in detail. 
Is there such a tool , if not a method i can do that in eclipse?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97599/static-analysis-tool-recommendation-for-java

Answer (score 1):

check this http://www.sourceinsight.com/

source insight

or http://code.google.com/intl/ko-KR/javadevtools/codepro/doc/index.html

this is free!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tool to generate a UML class diagramm from the code, e.g. [Fujaba CASE tool](http://www.fujaba.de/).

Some of the popular metrics tools (some as Eclipse plugin) have good visualizations:

- [Sonar](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+Eclipse),
- [Usus](http://code.google.com/p/projectusus/)
- [Google Metrics](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/codepro/doc/features/metrics/metrics.html)
- [Google CodePro Analytix](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/codepro/doc/index.html)

If you want something more esoteric, you can listen to [this software engineering podcast](http://www.se-radio.net/2009/03/episode-130-code-visualization-with-michele-lanza/) about code visualization, e.g. [Code Cities](http://www.inf.usi.ch/faculty/lanza/Downloads/Wett2008a.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://code.google.com/p/projectusus/ for free

The best I have seen (but commercial) ist structure 101 : http://www.headwaysoftware.com/products/

Or you can extract all the information you need yourself using dependency finder: http://depfind.sourceforge.net/

I have a little hobby (scala) project that uses dependency finder to create graphml files which can then be viewed using yed. Only even look at this if you are willing to fool around with the source code. https://github.com/schauder/Dependency-Manager