# Static code analysis tool for Java EE project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tortoisesvn, static-analysis

What are the available static code analysis tools for Java EE proects .
I want the tool to be stand alone or it should be integrated with tortoise SVN (like plugin).

Comment: In case of SVN plug in : It should create a report if it finds any violations , and stop the user to commit the code to SVN.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static Analysis tool recommendation for Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97599/static-analysis-tool-recommendation-for-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried PMD it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the standalone tool:
[Source Monitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sm20.html)

Or [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/), which can be used as stanalone or with maven/ant.

Comment: is there any wiki/manual available for this tool ?

Comment: Source Monitor is quite easy. For Sonar - http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Use+Sonar